# How to reduce page size of output from less -X, or git log?

Tags: bash, git, less

*I am not sure if this is a git problem, or a less problem, or a batch problem, or something else - so I will simply describe my problem in the way I experience it.*

I am using batch in my terminal, and I am using git.
With commands like "git log", I get an interactive output where I can scroll up and down, and when I quit (q), a snapshot of the latest scroll position stays as printed output in the terminal. If I did not scroll, the first line is typically `commit *** (HEAD -> 1.x) ***`, so the first line of the output.

The same happens when I use `less -X` on a large file.

*I assume that `git log` uses `less` as the pager, but I don't really know for sure. The `git config core.pager` is empty for me. So I describe both as distinct problems, and leave it to the answer to clarify.*

Now I changed my `PS1` in `~/.bashrc` to start with a line break. I do this to make sure the bash prompt always starts at the beginning, even if the output from the last command does not end with a line break. I am not 100% happy with this, but it is the current way I do it.

Now with this change, the first line of a `git log` or `less -X` always scrolls out of view.

Is there a way to reduce the number of lines that remain as printed output?
And, is this something to be configured in git or less or elsewhere?

### EDIT: Example

Let's see I use `less -X` to view a file with 100 lines, in a terminal with 5 lines visible at once. I view the file without scrolling down, and then quit with 'q'.

The complete file content is like this:

```
first line from file
second line from file
third line from file
fourth line from file
fifth line from file
sixth line from file
[..]
```

Or if this was a git history, the first line would be like `* *** (HEAD) ***`.

With a normal bash prompt PS1, the output after quitting `less -X` would be like this - fifth and following lines are cut off:

```
first line from file
second line from file
third line from file
fourth line from file
~ $
```

With the PS1 starting with a line break, the output after quitting `less -X` would be like this - so the first line is scrolled out of view:

```
second line from less output
third line from less output
fourth line from less output

~ $
```

What I try to achieve is this - fourth line is cut off:

```
first line from less output
second line from less output
third line from less output

~ $
```

So I need to reduce the output size after quitting by one line, or find another solution that has the same effect.

Comment: `less` is indeed the defauot pager for `git`. One way to configure `less` is to set the `LESS` environment variable (see `man less`) to the options used for this program. Since I did not understand from your question, what exactly you want to achieve, I can't say which _less_ options to use, but I suggest that you look at the available options (there are plenty).

Comment: @user1934428 The goal would be to reduce the number of lines printed after quitting `less -X` by one.

Comment: I don't think `less` has such an option, as this is a pretty unusual requirement. How about approaching it from the other side: If you remove the final newline from the output you are paging through (the git history in your case), you should get the desired effects with the default settings for `less`.